# BackFill individual Airflow TaskGroups

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, mwaa

Looks like SubDagOperator is being deprecated in Airflow in favor of TaskGroups. Since TaskGroups are only a UI grouping concept and all tasks still belong to the same DAG, I think some functionalities such as being able to BackFill an individual task group (which you can do with SubDags) will not be available.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if not, what could be a workaround to this limitation?

Thanks!

Comment: From CLI, you can do `airflow dags backfill -t {task group id} {dag name}`.  Since Tasks within a TaskGroup have `{task group id}.{task id}` as their task_id, you can still use `-t` option of backfill to whitelist the task lists to backfill.  I don't know how to do in UI though.